# iOS UIAutomation - Unable to record script

Tags: ios, instruments, ios-ui-automation

I am facing a strange problem. I am unable to record any script while running Instrument for UI Automation. Based on this article
http://www.verious.com/article/test-automation-uiautomation-example-with-xcode-instruments/

I tried to record some user action from my device as well as simulator but Instrument just don't generate any script to replay.

I've restarted machine, x-code, instrument etc multiple times. I am on X code 4.6.3 with Instrument version 4.6, mac os version: 10.8.4

Any help!!!

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're new you should follow the official tutorial.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW83

Also is a good idea at first runs yours app in iPhone by Xcode, and after that open Instruments and record some script, in this way the target is already determined, for your app on the iphone.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was with x code installation. I un-installed and reinstalled x code and now i am able to record the scripts with same steps.